# If I don't use XOR in Davies–Meyer, does it remain collision resistant?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

If I don't use XOR in Davies–Meyer construction like in picture 2, does the function remain collision resistant?

[image]

Comment: Is Enc from a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#Definition)? ​ ​

Comment: This reduces the pre-image resistance to $n/2$ bits via a meet-in-the-middle attack, but I don't see how it would weaken collision resistance.

Answer (score 3):

Let $h=E_{x_i}(z_{i-1})$ in your suggestion. Let $z'=E^{-1}_{x'}(h)$. This gives a collision between between $(x_i,z_{i-1})$ and $(x',z').$

The XOR makes this attack difficult.

Comment: How would the attacker reach the chaining state $z^\prime$? That sounds like a first pre-image attack to me, so your "attack" only works if you can pull of a much more difficult attack already.

Comment: What you describe is a *freestart collision*, not a proper *collision*. Freestart collisions aren't necessarily a problem, for example they're trivial to find for SHA-3 using essentially the same technique you describe.

Comment: @CodesInChaos, can you describe a proper collision in the context of this question?